# Using 1 to bitwise set all bits of a byte

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I currently hardcode a value to 255 like so

```
uint8_t outStates       = 0xFF;
```

But I have a macro that would be cleaner to use

```
#define TCA9555_LOW (1)
```

And the only way I would think of to do it would be this way, but is seems inefficient and uglier to read, hich is not what I want

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    outStates |= (TCA9555_LOW << i);
}
```

Is there a prettier way to set all bits at once, using an easy to read macro of value 1 ?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't get you, can you put an example of what you want to fill and how?

Comment: `(1u << nbit) -1` gives you nbit `1`  bits. Is that what you need?

Comment: My point is, outStates needs to be set to 255, but just giving it a value of 0xFF looks llike a magic number. I am looking for a clean way to set a byte's value to 0b11111111, without for looping through each bit and doing byte |= bit; 8 times

Comment: You may just use `uint8_t outStates = 0b11111111;` for compilers that understand it.

Comment: an easy way to set all the bits to 1:   uint8_t outStates = -1;

Comment: What's the meaning of your macro? Is it supposed to be just a true/false indicator, as in "is this thingy active-low"? Or is it actually a number, as in "how many twiddles in this thingy"? Because if it's a boolean, then don't rely on it being `1` -- the C convention is that anything other than zero is true, not just one, and in any case, doing arithmetic with booleans is just confusing to a reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to to set each bit to the value of `TCA9555_LOW` without looping. To achieve that, you can use the following:

```c
uint8_t outStates =
     ( TCA9555_LOW << 7 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 6 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 5 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 4 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 3 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 2 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 1 )
   | ( TCA9555_LOW << 0 );
```

---

But if we think about it, there's only two possible outcomes. The following would be equivalent:

```c
uint8_t outStates = TCA9555_LOW ? 0xFF : 0x00;
```

---

Finally, on the same basis, we could use the following:

```c
uint8_t outStates = 0;
if (TCA9555_LOW)
   outStates = ~outStates;
```

---

In the first two cases, the compiler should fold the expression into a single constant. Maybe even the third.

Comment: The entire bit twiddling sequence is equivalent to `TCA9555_LOW * 255`. Why not use that?

Comment: @njuffa, That's extremely close the the second solution, but less clear. (Multiplication when dealng with bits is jarring.) I mean, there's a million ways of doing this that matches the OP's criteria, so I'm going to stick to three. I don't recommend any of them over what the OP already had. If it's too unclear, give it a name!

Comment: the solutions 2 and 3 are actually beautiful as it lets you change the polarity of your macro and it sets up the firmware in consequence. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#define TCA9555_LOW (1)
/* if TCA9555_LOW is set, we use active-low logic, 
   so default to all eight bits set */
#define TCA9555_DEFAULT (TCA9555_LOW ? 0xff : 0)

...

uint8_t outStates = TCA9555_DEFAULT;
```

Don't make it too hard. If you're doing low-level bit fiddling like I get the feeling you are doing, everyone will understand it when you say that "these eight bits need to be ones here", and `0xff` is as clear a way to present that as there is. (If it was 21 bits instead, I might go with `(1 << 21) - 1`, instead of `0x1fffff` just to spare the reader from counting the digits, but a full byte is clear even without that.)

Answer (score 1):

Set it to `-1`.

C standard says:

> 6.3.1.3  Signed and unsigned integers
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is
> converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than  the
> maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type until the
> value is in the range of the new type.

Thus setting `uint8_t` to `-1` will actually set it `UINT8_MAX + 1 - 1` what is 255. This method works for all unsigned types.

It is a simple, portable and convenient method to set all bits to one.